# SwiftUI how to fill a List row with the VStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation

I want to make a `List`, and press the row(cell) then pop a button, press the button navigation a new view.

Like this gif:

[image]

The problems are:

1. Only press the green area(`RowView`), the "Add" button part (`MenuView`) pop up. I want press the whole cell yellow part to popup the add button part.
2. How to disable the gray selection part, or just remove the gray color?
3. In my code below, `isAddPressed` is `false` by default, then the cell shouldn't be pressed, not sure why is still navigation to destination view.

Here is my code:

**MenuView** (Add button part)

```
struct MenuView: View {
    var onAdd: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add") {
                onAdd()
            }.background(Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(Rectangle())
        }
    }
}
```

**RowView** The green part.

```
struct RowView: View {
    var foo: Foo
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(foo.title)
        }
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

**AView1** The main part.

```
struct AView1: View {

    @State var foos: [Foo] = [Foo(title: "a"), Foo(title: "b"), Foo(title: "c")]
    @State var isDisplayMenue: Bool = false
    @State var isAddPressed: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
                List {
                    ForEach(foos, id:\.self) { foo in
                        ZStack {
                            Color(.yellow)
                            VStack {
                                RowView(foo: foo)
                                    .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
                                        isDisplayMenue = true
                                    })
                                    .background(
                                        NavigationLink(
                                            destination: isAddPressed ? Text("Destination") : nil,
                                            isActive: $isAddPressed,
                                            label: {
                                                EmptyView()
                                            })

                                    )
                                    .padding()
                                if isDisplayMenue {
                                    MenuView() {
                                        isAddPressed = true
                                        isDisplayMenue = false
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }.onAppear() {
                    isAddPressed = false
                }
            })

        }

    }
}
```

Here are some not important part:

```
struct DestionationView: View {
    @Binding var isAddPressed: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Text("Destination")
    }
}

struct Foo: Hashable {
    var title: String
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: there is 3 questions here, which is not good! you should make 3 questions, also the topic of your question is unclear and not mach to those 3 questions!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a yellow rectangle on top of the cell and add the .onTap {}. There will be your popping down cell.
2. Use introspect to grab the tableview and assign the cell to the tableview and modify the UItableview on disappear. You can check this answer. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660468
3. You need to modify the button's disable modifier.

Answer (score 0):

1. With the help of

   .contentShape(Rectangle())
   I made `VStack` can be clicked by `onTapGesture` to display the menu.
2. With `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())` then the default gray selection of SwiftUI list cell no displayed any more.

With both 1 and 2 I made the `VStack` take the whole width of the screen/List row width.